# How to block access to a GET request

Tags: apache-2.2, joomla

Someone is sending malicious code through a form on Joomla.

I tried to delete the form but it didn't block the access.

The URI is /index.php?option=com_contact&task=view&contact_id=3&Itemid=45

How to write a rule on .htaccess that blocks access to this specific GET request?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for Apache 2.4+:

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /option=com_contact&task=view&contact_id=3&Itemid=45/">
 Require All Denied
</If>
```

This uses a regular expression, that could be too specific, so you might have to adjust it.

Comment: Forgot to metion I don't know what is the version I'm working on.
Most probably is 2.2. I'll send an email to the server admins.